# Why is IE 8 CSS zoom so different (and broken) than IE 7?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, zooming, ie8-browser-mode

IE 8 appears to have implement the "zoom" CSS attribute completely differently than IE 7.

Here is a quick example:

```
<style>
   .outer { position: relative; width: 500px; height: 500px; }
   .inner { position: absolute; width: 250px; height: 500px; font-size: 50px; }
   .one { top: 0; left: 0; }
   .two { top: 0; left: 250px; }
</style>
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner one">one</div>
  <div class="inner two">two</div>
</div>
```

This ideally would show 2 divs that are side by side - each 500px wide and they do not overlap eachother.

In IE 7 the "two" div is what you would expect - and this works in general with many different things - everything inside the "outer" div is scaled up to a scale of 2x just like you would expect.

But in IE 8 this is not the case - the "two" div is still only 250px from the left; it appears only the text inside the "two" div scaled up - nothing else really gets scaled (such as the position context of every child element!!!).

Things start overlapping horribly wrong in IE 8, so I actually am forced to have a tag like this

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />
```

That way IE 8 will render like IE 7, making the benefits of IE 8 moot - so now everything on the page must work with IE 7's crappy layout engine (not like IE 8 is so much better here, but at least there are some better things in IE 8 layout engine).

Oh and guess what - even now (July 2013) the stats for our site indicate that over 90% of our users primarily use IE 8 - so, yea... making new features that only work for less than 10% of your customers is not an option (many of whom do not even have the administrative rights to install anything new because these are enterprise customers using PCs in an office).

**Edit**
To be clear: It is clear that the implementation of Zoom changed in IE 8 - my question is why did IE 8 change this behavior when clearly it has made things so much worse.

I can give other examples of functionality that is plainly impossible with IE 8, but with IE 7 it is easy to accomplish with css zoom - so that is clear evidence that IE 8's implementation of zoom is just plain **wrong** - so why did they do it?

Comment: It's not clear what your question really is. IE changed the way zoom worked (optical zoom vs. layout zoom) between v7 and v8 in order to improve the user-experience with Zoom.

Comment: My question is "why did it change" - it appears your answer is "to imrpove the user-experience with the css zoom attribute" - but in reality the user-experience is much much worse. Can you please be more clear as to what is actually improved?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/03/25/internet-explorer-8-and-adaptive-zoom.aspx

Comment: Thanks MiniRagnarok - this article explains it in detail - it appears my usage of "zoom" is not actually what Microsoft intended it to be used for. I am trying to use it as an alternative to the "transform:scale(xx)" which CSS3 provides - in which I want to scale everything - and microsoft has interpreted zoom to simply make text more readable (like the user wants to make just the text bigger) - so what Microsoft did was to assume that the zoom was being used only for one particular purpose and then changed it to better suit that one single-minded purpose, meanwhile breaking the functionality.